# ADBannerView contents

Tags: iphone, ios, iad, adbannerview

Is there any way of knowing which ad loaded in an ADBannerView, or in any way control the ad that loads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't anything on the interface to interogate which ad was loaded when you receive the [bannerActionDidFinish](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/ADBannerViewDelegate_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/ADBannerViewDelegate/bannerViewActionDidFinish:) callback.  I am guessing that the [advertisingSection](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/ADBannerView_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/ADBannerView/advertisingSection) property (currently reserved for future use) might contain some meta data about the loaded ad, but that is just speculation.

There isn't a way of controlling what the [ADBannerView](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/ADBannerView_Ref/Reference/Reference.html) loads programmatically.  You can explicitly exclude keywords via the admin interface.